# Proof of existence of maximal matching

Tags: proof-verification, graph-theory

How do I prove that, for any graph $G$ and any edges $e$, $f$ of $G$ which are not incident with a common vertex, there exists a maximal matching of $G$ containing both $e$ and $f$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Start with definition. What is *maximal* matching?

Comment: A matching P, of graph G, is said to be maximal if no other edges of G can be added to P because every node is matched to another node.

Comment: That's right. Can $e$ and $f$ belong to the same matching?

Comment: yes they can...

Comment: Can you extend any such matching while it is not maximal?